# Find Sum of variable 10x greater than sum during different date

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that keeps a record of each song played on the radio with a timestamp. I am trying to find songs that have increased plays 10x since 6/1/16, I ran this:

```
SELECT SONG_ID
FROM StationPlays
WHERE StationPlays.DATE > '2016-06-01' AND SONG_ID IN 
(
  SELECT SONG_ID
  FROM StationPlays
  WHERE StationPlays.DATE < '2016-06-01'
  GROUP BY SONG_ID
  HAVING SUM(SPINS) < 1000
)
GROUP BY SONG_ID
HAVING SUM(SPINS) > 10000
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically where I can just set 1000 as a variable and use 10*Variable to find all songs that have increased 10 fold (or 20 fold or more) in the last x days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT SONG_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM StationPlays
WHERE StationPlays.DATE > '2016-06-01' 
GROUP BY SONG_ID, StationPlays.DATE
HAVING COUNT(*) > (10 * (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM StationPlays SP2
                         WHERE SP2.DATE > '2016-06-01'
                             AND SP2.SONG_ID = StationPlays.SONG_ID))
```

Comment: Does COUNT(*) count the number of rows in the query? What is the benefit to giving the subquery an alias?

Comment: I just added "Date" to the Group By.  Count will count the number of rows per day -- the number of times the song was played each day.